# org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException

Tags: hibernate

I am working on hibernate mapping and everything else was working fine except the PropertyAccessException i am getting when hibernate trying to persist my object in to the system.
below is the stack trace

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.raisonne.tr.model.destination.Destination.uuid

    org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:195)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:199)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3605)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3321)
    org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:204)
    org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys$Nullifier.isNullifiable(ForeignKeys.java:160)
    org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys$Nullifier.nullifyTransientReferences(ForeignKeys.java:92)
    org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys$Nullifier.nullifyTransientReferences(ForeignKeys.java:70)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:311)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:144)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:535)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:527)
    org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:241)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:292)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:240)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:320)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:266)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:243)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:154)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:479)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:357)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:144)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:535)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:527)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:523)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:342)
    $Proxy17.saveOrUpdate(Unknown Source)
    com.raisonne.tr.dao.impl.GenericDAOImpl.makePersistance(GenericDAOImpl.java:170)
    com.raisonne.tr.service.impex.impl.DestinationImportServiceImpl.startDestinationImport(DestinationImportServiceImpl.java:130)
    com.raisonne.tr.backoffice.actions.impex.DestinationImportAction.destinationImport(DestinationImportAction.java:118)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:169)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:199)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3605)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3321)
    org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:204)
    org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys$Nullifier.isNullifiable(ForeignKeys.java:160)
    org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys$Nullifier.nullifyTransientReferences(ForeignKeys.java:92)
    org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys$Nullifier.nullifyTransientReferences(ForeignKeys.java:70)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:311)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:144)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:535)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:527)
    org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:241)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:292)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:240)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:320)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:266)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:243)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:154)
```

here is the code of the getter and setter methods

```
public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}
```

and the mapping portion is

```
<id name="uuid" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="UUID" />
    <generator class="uuid"/>
</id>
```

i am new to hibernate so not much idea what exactly is the problem my destination class has refrence to few other class which are also getting persist when i am persisting Destination class

any help in this regard is much appricitaed

**Edit1**

Well the problem seems to be with respect to the relation i have defined in the Destination class as well in the mapping file..

```
private Set<PlaceToVisit> placesToVisit=new HashSet<PlaceToVisit>();

public Set<PlaceToVisit> getPlacesToVisit() {
    return placesToVisit;
}

public void setPlacesToVisit(Set<PlaceToVisit> placesToVisit) {
    this.placesToVisit = placesToVisit;
}

public void addPlaceToVisit(PlaceToVisit placeToVisit){
    placeToVisit.setDestination(this);
    this.placesToVisit.add(placeToVisit);
}
```

as well in mapping file as

```
<set name="placesToVisit" table="PLACETOVISIT" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="save-update">
    <key>
        <column name="DESTINATIONID" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="PlaceToVisit" />
</set>
```

while i have following in the PlaceToVisit class

```
<id name="uuid" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="UUID" />
    <generator class="uuid"/>
</id>

<property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="NAME" />
</property>

<many-to-one name="destination" class="Destination" fetch="join">
    <column name="DESTINATION" />
</many-to-one>
```

and other getter setter for this class

when i am removing all refrences of the associations from the destination class everything working fine but adding any relation entry in Destination mapping file showing me the above described error.

Comment: What is the version of Hibernate that you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error may be caused by the fact that the object of some other type was found where the object of type `Destination` was expected.

For example, if some other class was accidentially added to `Collection<Destination>` via unchecked cast.

Comment: @umesh: Note the different foreign key column names (`DESTINATION` and `DESTINATIONID`) and wrong `inverse = "false"` value. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html for reference.

Comment: what you suggested in your comment is one of the major reason for the behavior..Thanks