# Need to restart JBoss after each test

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I have a complex testcase that eventually breaks down to a `entityMgr.persist(rra);`. The first time I start my testcase after the JBoss EAP 6.2.4 has been started, it will succeed as expected. The second time I start this testcase, it will always fail with the following exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of de.nvg.aelkf.ruleengine.dto.RelRegelArbeitsschluesselId.gueltigAbTimestamp
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of de.nvg.aelkf.ruleengine.dto.RelRegelArbeitsschluesselId.gueltigAbTimestamp
    ... 130 more
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.ArquillianProxyException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException : IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of de.nvg.aelkf.ruleengine.dto.RelRegelArbeitsschluesselId.gueltigAbTimestamp [Proxied because : Original exception caused: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException]
    ... 172 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    ... 217 more
```

The persist itself always works when I use the application. Only when starting this testcase for the n+1th time I will get this error. Before figuring out that I have to restart my server every time (btw. using Arquillian 1.1.5) I got an OutOfMemory exception of some kind (something with PermGen...). Then my thought was that JBoss has some memory leak.

Is this a bug? I can't understand this exception

Comment: I believe the second time when you are setting the property its failing and its not able to wrap up into the exception as the class is missing or not found in the current class loader. See this if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616141/org-hibernate-propertyaccessexception-illegalargumentexception

Comment: Besides that I don't understand what you are trying to say, the link didn't help me; as I said, the code during runtime works perfectly fine

Comment: Now I will sometimes get the exception ` javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of de.nvg.aelkf.ruleengine.dto.RegelId.gueltigAbTimestamp` for ALL my testcases. But it is not reproducible and seems to occur at random times.

Answer (score 0):

Really strange.
I suggest you to try your test with remote `JBoss 7.1.1` or `Wildfly 8.1`. And post here the results.