# Abstract Entity Persister Method get Property Values Illegal Argument Exception in Class

Tags: java, hibernate

- I'm getting error on DAO class Object[] property value    variable,method of getPropertyValues(Object object ,EntityMode.Pojo);  Is it correct way I am accessing property values based on property    names ?please let me know where I have made mistaken ?
- Using hibertnate-core 3.6.1 Final.jar.

**My full Stack Trace :**

```
  [ERROR] IllegalArgumentException in class: com.zpmc.ecs.domain.ExportReport, getter method of property: description       -  (BasicPropertyAccessor.java:194) 
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.zpmc.ecs.domain.ExportReport.description
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3857)
    at com.zpmc.ecs.autoexportbean.AutoExportListenerService.getAllTables(AutoExportListenerService.java:327)
    at com.zpmc.ecs.autoexportbean.AutoExportListenerService.buildReport(AutoExportListenerService.java:154)
    at com.zpmc.ecs.autoexportbean.AutoExportListenerService.getAutoExportExcel(AutoExportListenerService.java:130)
    at com.zpmc.ecs.autoexportbean.MyTask.run(AutoExportListenerBean.java:137)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:172)
    ... 9 more
```

**Pojo Class :**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name ="T_KPI_AUTO_EXPORT_CONFIG")
public class ExportReport implements Serializable  {
private String description;
@Column(name ="Description", nullable = false)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**DAO Class Method :**

```
public List <String> getAllTables() throws SQLException {
 Map<String, ClassMetadata> classMetaDataMap = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getAllClassMetadata();
         for(Map.Entry<String, ClassMetadata> metaDataMap : classMetaDataMap.entrySet()) {
ClassMetadata classMetadata = metaDataMap.getValue();
                AbstractEntityPersister abstractEntityPersister = (AbstractEntityPersister) classMetadata;
                tableName = abstractEntityPersister.getTableName();
String[] propertyNames = abstractEntityPersister.getPropertyNames();
  for(int i=0;i<propertyNames.length;i++){

                    Object[] propertyvalue =abstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValues(ExportReport.class,EntityMode.POJO);


                    System.out.println(propertyType+"Columns: " + propertyNames+"ddddd"+propertyvalue);
                      System.out.println(propertyNames[i]);
                      System.out.println(propertyvalue[i]);
                  }

}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616141/org-hibernate-propertyaccessexception-illegalargumentexception

Comment: Thanks for replied me ,actually I want to fetch data from database using hibernate ? I'm not achieving result please let me know any alternate way ?

Comment: How do u want to fetch data, from which table, what props u required in query ? Which DB u r using ?

Comment: I'm using oracle database , I need to get data all database tables .Example :like using jdbc template ,but my requirement using hibernate template let me know Is it possible ?above code I'm getting all tables using getAllClassMetada .

Comment: Why r u fetching all tables in DB at once ? Is there any special reason ? It is recommended to fetch the data as & when required. Since u r using Hibernate, u can get all child tables when u request a parent with `FetchType.Eager`. I suggest u to use `hibernateTemplate.find(sqlQuery);` to get tables from the DB.

Comment: thanks for replied me.actually I need to export to database Apache poi excel file . yes I'm using hibernate template .`private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate; @Autowired public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) { hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory); }`

Comment: Not sure but try changing `EntityMode.POJO` to `EntityMode.Map` Check [this](http://www.javased.com/index.php?api=org.hibernate.metadata.ClassMetadata).

Comment: The root cause of the above error is `IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class`. May be somewhere in ur app u have created list of say `String` & mapped it with say `Integer` type. Check ur mappings of all classes.

Comment: Now I have changed my code object to `List<ExportReport> listCriteria=hibernateTemplate.findByExample(objectClass);` ,now I am getting pojo class variables not include constraint column , also not sequence of database column wise ?

Comment: now finally I achieve like this ,but one more I have getting separate constraint column name as a database column name and Pojo class declare variables ? Is it possible to make all in single list ? Example constraint column name : `String Id = abstractEntityPersister.getIdentifierPropertyName(); String[] columns = abstractEntityPersister.getPropertyColumnNames(Id);String[] propertyNames = classMetadata.getPropertyNames();`

Comment: If this solves ur purpose then definitely u can do this.

Comment: How to use ResultSetMetaData using jave ,hibernate?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/HibernateCollectionMappingMap.htm). Never ask another question in one question until & unless the context is same. Better to create a separate post.